# How can I store and delete session data in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.5.  I would like to store session data in a table.  When the session is over, the data should be deleted.  Can anyone help me accomplish this task?

Comment: check this [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#driver-prerequisites), do google and the ask question  !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Redis](https://redis.io/) for storing and destroying session data within a Laravel application. One of the most apparent use cases for Redis is using it as a session cache.

If you are determined to store your session data in a database, check out this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session) that gives you the option on how to handle session data.

You need to change the session configuration file is stored in `config/session.php` to the database option and created the needed table.